# ng-options displays blank selected option, even though ng-model is defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created a plunkr to emphasize the problem, perhaps it's because the source of the ng-repeat is a function, I am not sure, but so far I've tried everything in order to solve this, and couldn't mange.

plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qQFsRM?p=preview

HTML

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc1" data-semver="1.2.0-rc1" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <ng-include src="'menu.html'">
  </ng-include>

</html>
```

Script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $httpBackend){
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.model.myJobs = {};
  $scope.refreshJobs = function(){

  }
});

app.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope){

$scope.model.locations = function(){
  var loc = [];
  loc[1] = 'Dublin';
  loc[2] = 'Stockholm';
  loc[3] = 'New Jersy';
  $scope.model.selectedLocationDef = loc.indexOf('Dublin');
  return loc;
}
  $scope.model.selectedLocation =  $scope.model.selectedLocationDef;

$scope.$watch('model.selectedLocation', function(location){
  $scope.refreshJobs(location);
});

});
```

Comment: It's a good thing to post external links to your live examples, but it would be better to post the actual code in this question (too). What if plunkr goes offline at some time?

Comment: I have revised my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Last I checked, Angular does not support the ability to bind array keys to ng-model via ng-options. You can, however, mimic this behavior using an object hash:

menu.html:

```
<div ng-controller="menuCtrl">
  <select ng-model="model.selectedLocation" ng-options="x.value as x.label for x in model.locations()">
  </select>
</div>
```

script.js:

```
$scope.model.locations = function(){
  var loc = [{
    value: 0,
    label: 'Dublin'
  }, {
    value: 1,
    label: 'Stockholm'
  }, {
    value: 2,
    label: 'New Jersey'
  }];

  $scope.model.selectedLocation =   1; // Set default value
  return loc;
}
```

Bear in mind that this will bind the integers to your model, and not the cities themselves. If you want your model value to be `Dublin`, `Stockholm`, or `New Jersey`, simply do:

menu.html:

```
<div ng-controller="menuCtrl">
  <select ng-model="model.selectedLocation" ng-options="name for name in model.locations()">
  </select>
</div>
```

script.js:

```
$scope.model.locations = function(){
  var loc = ['Dublin', 'Stockholm', 'New Jersey'];
  $scope.model.selectedLocation =   'Dublin'; // Set default value
  return loc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Only that if you'll do it like that you won't be able to change the value becuase you'll be setting the model.selectedLocation attribute over and over again

Answer (score 13):

If you use an array as model, then the model is a string not a number. So you need to convert the number to string. Just try

```
$scope.model.selectedLocation = '1';
```

Comment: @zsong I did not post this as a new question, but I have something similar. Not sure why it is not selecting the right option.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DmvqkS9SqTfRQQH59p72?p=preview